# Google sheets - is import DPD parcel status possible?

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to figure out whether it is possible to import latest parcel status from DPD.
For example, I would like to get 'Delivered' status from below link and import it to google sheets:

https://tracking.dpd.de/status/en_DE/parcel/05252044194808

Any attempts with importxml are, however, empty. Any chance there is a way to download the latest status to Google Sheets? Perhaps that site is secured from scrapping?

Answer (score 0):

`IMPORTXML` and `IMPORTHTML` would return data whenever the web page information is not generated through `JAVASCRIPT`, disabling `JAVASCRIPT` on the web page you are trying to scrape data from shows no data, so most likely the whole content is generated through Javascript dynamically and that's the reason why those methods don't return any information.